# Add a navigation drawer to blank activity

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, navigation-drawer

I have created an entire project on a blank activity(Android Studio). I want to add a navigation drawer without hampering with my previous code.Is there a way to add a navigation drawer to a blank activity, if yes please do guide.

Comment: Check this link https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html

Comment: @Swr7der thank you, Is it possible if you could send a source code,totally fine if you can't

Comment: It is, but you should try to learn and code on your own. It would be good for you. If ,after that, you are facing problem then post here.There are peers to help you. Happy coding :)

Comment: @Anonymous Android Studio lets you create templates. File > new > activity > Navigation Drawer Activity. Then read the code that android studio has generated

Comment: @Swr7der Thank You

Comment: @RafiduzzamanSonnet ,I got it,thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step1:Include navigation view to your xml file which will be inflated by yor activity on create.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<include
    layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />
```

step2:initialize views

```
 private NavigationView navigationView;
private DrawerLayout drawer;
```

step3: sent the event on drawer close and open

```
ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.openDrawer, R.string.closeDrawer) {

        @Override
        public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
            // Code here will be triggered once the drawer closes as we dont want anything to happen so we leave this blank
            super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            // Code here will be triggered once the drawer open as we dont want anything to happen so we leave this blank
            super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
        }
    };

    //Setting the actionbarToggle to drawer layout
    drawer.setDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);

    //calling sync state is necessary or else your hamburger icon wont show up
    actionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();
}
```

hope this helps how set the navigation drawer.

Answer (score 0):

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/icon">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/mainContent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lvLeft"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:background="#ff8800"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lvRight"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:background="#0077ff"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: You should add explanation to the answer, in addition to formatted code